# Рефакторинг кода PHP

Tags: php, mysql, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте. Пятой точкой чувствую, что можно сделать красивее... подскажите где бы Вы оптимизировали?

```
private function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $group=null, $order = null)
{
    $result = 'SELECT ' . $rows . ' FROM ' . $table;
    if($join != null)
    {
        $result .= ' LEFT JOIN ' . $join;
    }
    if ($where != null)
    {
        $result .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
    }
    if($group !=null)
    {
        $result .= ' GROUP BY ' . $group;
    }
    if ($order != null)
    {
        $result .= ' ORDER BY ' . $order;
    }
    $query = $this->mysqli->query($result) or die($mysqli->error);
    return $query;
}

public function startSelect($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $group=null, $order = null)
{
    return $this->select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $group=null, $order = null);
}

$database = new Database;

foreach ($database->startSelect('callback', 'callback.id_callback, comment_callback, theme_callback, COUNT(likes.id_likes) as likes', 'likes ON callback.id_callback = likes.id_callback_likes','','callback.id_callback','COUNT(likes.id_likes) DESC') as $value)
{
    echo $value['comment_callback'];
}
```

Comment: А если нужен не LEFT JOIN? Какую задачу решает данный велосипед?

Comment: Если даже не хотите применять готовые решения, то хоть посмотрите что там есть и как устроено. Рекомендую https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql

Comment: начните с того, чтобы все конструкции передавать не отдельными параметрами, а массивом с соответствующими ключами

Comment: @teran, можете привести небольшой пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Алексей вызывать следует не `select('*', null, 'id > 20', )` и т.п. а `select(['fields' => "id, title", 'where' => ['id >' => 20], 'group' => [...]])` и т.д.

Comment: @Алексей для чего, все-таки вы решили написать эти два метода?

Comment: @tutankhamun, я старался руководствоваться статьи https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-php-7oohabits/index.html

Comment: @Алексей пока не читал, но старайтесь вдумчиво и осторожно относиться к статьям по PHP такой давности. Некоторые подходы сильно поменялись с 2009 года. Советую смотреть на исходники современных разработок. Хотя некоторые идеи могут оказаться очень хорошими.

Comment: Лучший рефакторинг в данном случае - не изобретать свою очередную ORM, а использовать готовую.

Comment: @ilyaplot Позволю себе не согласиться. Нужно понимать что мы используем и зачем. Если на вопрос __зачем?__ программист имеет хотя бы для себя понятный ответ - это весомый повод написать очередной велосипед :)

Comment: Кстати код в вопросе ну как-то совсем не ORM. Вот я до сих пор не понимаю какие задачи он решает. Я бы вопрос удалил, а если есть необходимость обсудить - создал бы чат. Я бы даже поучаствовал (хотя-бы просто почитал)

Comment: @tutankhamun, эта функция создает запрос в базу данных с необходимыми параметрами.